# Com.Theartofdev.Edmodo.Cropper library result code cancelled

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I could not get the result code "OK" OnActivityResult using Com.Theartofdev.Edmodo.Cropper library. It was resulting cancelled even though I am actually pressing the crop from it, Since the library will automatically display the tool for cropping. using this code. It will let you pick image from your device and when I am pressing the crop nothing happens and found out the resultcode is cancelled.

```
CropImage.Builder()
                  .SetGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.On).SetCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.Oval).SetFixAspectRatio(true)
                  .Start(this);
```

[image]
(Image not mine, came from here "https://bintray.com/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper#")

My goal is to get the uri from the OnActivityResult and display it on a cropimageview.

```
 CropImageView cropImageView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            


            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.cropView);

            cropImageView = (CropImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.cropImageView);

        
            CropImage.Builder()
              .SetGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.On).SetCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.Oval).SetFixAspectRatio(true)
              .Start(this);

             StartActivityForResult(Intent, 200);


        }




        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {

            if (requestCode == CropImage.PickImageChooserRequestCode)
            {
                try
                {
   
                    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.GetActivityResult(data);
                    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                    {

                        Android.Net.Uri resultUri = result.Uri;
                        cropImageView.SetImageUriAsync(resultUri);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Error", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }


            }
        }
```

It says that on the documentation just use the OnActivityResult to get the cropped image from the tool but I could not make the result code to be "Ok". I really guess I'm doing it wrong or I am missing lots of parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the objective by rewriting the OnActivityResult from the old one to this,

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CropImageActivityRequestCode)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.GetActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri resultUri = result.Uri;
                profilepiC.SetImageURI(resultUri);
            }
            else if (resultCode == (Result)CropImage.CropImageActivityResultErrorCode)
            {
                System.Exception error = result.Error;
                Toast.MakeText(this, error.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

also by removing this line from OnCreate,

```
         StartActivityForResult(Intent, 200);
```

And i did just use a simple imageview rather than a cropviewimage.